# Function killed. Error: quota exceeded

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Im working with Firebase's cloud functions on the Spark Plan.

I'm using a cronJob to invoke a function every 2 min.

I have recently gotten this error:

> Function killed. Error: quota exceeded

When trying to deploy I get a similar error:

> Deploy Error: Function load error: Error: quota exceeded

I know there is a quota on the spark plan but my stats are as follows:

118 Executions

207 Total invocations

The spark plan says you get 125,000/month free invocations is there a limit of executions? Ive tried deploying a new function but I get the same errors.

What quota am I exceeding?

Comment: This is not a programming question suitable for Stack Overflow.  You should use a more appropriate support channel instead (such as troubleshooting over email).  https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: The first price of advice on that site is ask on Stack Overflow. And firebase is apparently very active on Stack Overflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It might not be relevant for Stackoverflow, but it is relevant none-the-less. I came from Google, being confused about it, and here was an answer.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Thanks for raising this question, it's something that should be covered better in the Firebase documentation.

You're correct that the Spark plan has a 125,000/month free function invocation limit. In addition however (and currently still unmentioned in the docs) there's per-day and a per-100-seconds limits too:

- You can have 5000 function invocations per day.
- You can have 50 function invocations per 100 seconds.

If these per-day or per-100s quotas are problematic for you, I suggest upgrading and using the free quota in the pay-as-you-go Blaze plan. You'll get even more free access ([two million (!) invocations free](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing)), and all these quotas practically go away (only some abuse protections remaining).

Comment: To add to the accepted answer, my problem was I was going over the daily quota for "CPU allocation in function invocations per day", which is "CPU allocation for the quota is measured in MHz-seconds". The weird thing was I didn't even run anything to trigger my functions.

Comment: You'll want to take a look at whether your functions (A) terminate properly; maybe your functions run for a very long time? (B) Are in some sort of infinite loop. Maybe some function is writing to some database path that triggers that same function? That'd run you out of quota very quickly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert. Something is definitely wrong with my scripts, I'm still learning Javascript :) But thank you, I'll take a look at what you recommended!

Comment: How about `Deploy Error: Function load error: Error: quota exceeded` then? This happens when trying to do a `firebase deploy`.

Comment: Looks like the same issue the OP hit. You're exceeding the quota, consider upgrading to the Blaze plan for a bigger free quota to play with.

Comment: Should the error go away on the next day? I also received such an error and it is because to much invocations but it only exceeded the per-day quota. Do I have to wait until the same day ends or the month in witch it exceeded?

Comment: If you only exceeded the daily quota, just waiting for the next day is enough. Consider changing from the Spark plan to the Blaze plan, which almost certainly won't cost you anything either but will give you much better free quotas.

Comment: I am on the Blaze plan but I am still exceeding my quota. But when I look at the google cloud console it says I have only used 26/36,000. I thought the whole point of the blaze plan was auto scaling. At the moment I am now stuck until tomorrow . But I don't have enough time to be stuck for a whole day!

Comment: Our awesome support folks can help! https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/?category=troubleshooting

Comment: Is this documented anywhere on firebase.google.com?