# Cloud function killed. Error: quota exceeded (Socket connections : per 100 seconds). Blaze Plan

Tags: sockets, firebase, google-cloud-functions

We're using Firebase's cloud functions on the Blaze Plan.
One cloud function makes resize and compress images from event, then it saves the image in Storage. After getting **"socket hang up"** error in another function (which also saves the image in Storage), I found the solution to this problem by setting this parameter to `reqOpts.forever = false` for `'@google-cloud/storage'`, this works well, but I saw in logs new error: **"Error: quota exceeded (Socket connections: per 100 seconds)"**. I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905204/function-killed-error-quota-exceeded), it says that using the Blaze plan, but we already use it already. How to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: Please open a ticket with Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: @DougStevenson ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved with the support of Firebase. At the moment, this problem does not repeat on the Blaze plan.