# Google Cloud Functions: warning Avoid nesting promises promise/no-nesting +5k registers

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have the following function on my firebase app.

But every time I deploy it i get this message:

> 142:12  warning  Avoid nesting promises  promise/no-nesting
>
> ✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)

```
exports.cronTravas = functions.database.ref('acoes').onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const acoes = change.after.val();
      var acoesNovas = [];
  var travas = {}

  for (var key in acoes) {
    var item = {
      'key': key,
      'ult': acoes[key].ult
    }
    acoesNovas[key.substring(0, 4)] = item;
  }

  return admin.database().ref().child('opcoesNew').orderByChild('strike').once('value')
  .then((snap) => {
    const opcoes = snap.val();

    travas['travasAlta'] = {}
    for (var data in opcoes) {
      travas['travasAlta'][data] = {}
      for (var ativo in opcoes[data]) {
        travas['travasAlta'][data][ativo] = {}

        var i = 0;
        for (var opcao in opcoes[data][ativo]) {
          i++;
          travas['travasAlta'][data][ativo] = calculaTravas(opcoes[data][ativo], acoesNovas[ativo].ult);
        }
      }
    }
    return travas;
  })
  .then(travas => {
    return admin.database().ref().update(travas).catch((error) => {
      return console.error(error);
    });
  })
});
```

That said, how can I remove this warning?

And, if it matters, this function is consuming a lot of quota generating this message in a few minutes:

> Error: quota exceeded (CPU allocation in function invocations : per
>   day, CPU allocation in function invocations : per day); to increase
>   quotas, enable billing in your project at xxxxxxx. Function cannot be
>   executed.

Is there a way to optimize it so that I can use this free quota without blowing it? (I know I can upgrade but I'm really trying to work on the free plan for now).

My database looks like this:

```
acoes (8)
opcoes
-datas(4)
--acao(8)
---opcao(160)
```

So, inside my 'opcoes' node I have 4 'datas' nodes and each one of them have 8 'acao' nodes and each one of them have '160' opcao nodes. So I have at least 5k nodes and I have to iterate through all of them every time the "acoes" nodes is updated (which is 1x per minute). Any ideas on how to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first warning should be solved with the following modifications to your code:

```
exports.cronTravas = functions.database.ref('acoes').onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const acoes = change.after.val();
  var acoesNovas = [];
  var travas = {}

  for (var key in acoes) {
    var item = {
      'key': key,
      'ult': acoes[key].ult
    }
    acoesNovas[key.substring(0, 4)] = item;
  }

  return admin.database().ref().child('opcoesNew').orderByChild('strike').once('value')
  .then((snap) => {
    const opcoes = snap.val();

    travas['travasAlta'] = {}
    for (var data in opcoes) {
      travas['travasAlta'][data] = {}
      for (var ativo in opcoes[data]) {
        travas['travasAlta'][data][ativo] = {}

        var i = 0;
        for (var opcao in opcoes[data][ativo]) {
          i++;
          travas['travasAlta'][data][ativo] = calculaTravas(opcoes[data][ativo], acoesNovas[ativo].ult);
        }
      }
    }
    // return travas;  <- Don't return travas here, as it is not a promise.
    // but return the promise returned by the update() method
    return admin.database().ref().update(travas);
  })
});
```

---

For the "quota exceeded" alerts, this SO may give you some directions: [Function killed. Error: quota exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905204/function-killed-error-quota-exceeded). Note that with your initial code, the Cloud Function is not terminated correctly.