# Firebase Cloud Storage/Functions - Error: quota exceeded when uploading images

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am getting the following error message in the Cloud Functions log:

> Quota exceeded for quota group 'FunctionCallsNonbillable' and limit 'CLIENT_PROJECT-100s'

What I am doing is that I upload some images through a client, and I have a listener on the Storage bucket to generate some thumbnails. When the thumbnails are generated, I write the image urls to Realtime Database.

When deleting, I listen to the URL deletions in the Realtime Database and deleting the original image and the thumbnail afterward.

Here is an image from the log:
[image]

And here is my code:

```js
// Imports for thumbnail generating
import sharp from "sharp"
import path from "path"
import os from "os"
import fs from "fs"
import { database, storage } from "./firebase"

const sizes = [640, 1024, 1440]


export const generateThumbnail = async object =>  {
  const {name: filePath, contentType} = object
  const fileName = path.basename(filePath)

  // Exit if not an image
  if (!contentType.startsWith("image/")) return console.log("✖ Not an image.")

  // Exit if the image is already a resized one.
  if (fileName.includes("thumb_")) return console.log("✖ Already processed image.")

  const bucket = storage.bucket(object.bucket)

  // Create paths
  const destination = path.dirname(filePath)
  const tempDir = os.tmpdir()

  const tempFile = path.join(tempDir, fileName)

  const thumbFileNames = sizes.map(size => `thumb_${size}_${fileName}`)
  const tempThumbFiles = thumbFileNames.map(thumbFileName => path.join(tempDir, thumbFileName))
  const thumbFiles = thumbFileNames.map(thumbFileName => path.join(destination, thumbFileName))

  // Download file from bucket.
  await bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempFile})
  console.log("Image downloaded locally to", tempFile)

  // Generate thumbnails using Sharp.
  await Promise.all(
    tempThumbFiles.map((tempThumbFile, index) =>
      sharp(tempFile).resize(sizes[index]).toFile(tempThumbFile)
    )
  )

  console.log("Thumbnails created. Now uploading...")
  // Uploading the thumbnails.
  await Promise.all(
    thumbFiles
      .map((thumbFile, index) =>
        bucket.upload(tempThumbFiles[index], {
          destination: thumbFile,
          metadata: {contentType}
        })
      ))

  // Once the thumbnails has been uploaded delete the local files to free up disk space.
  fs.unlinkSync(tempFile)
  tempThumbFiles.forEach(tempThumbFile => fs.unlinkSync(tempThumbFile))


  // Now get the URLs of the uploaded images, both the original's and the thumbnails'.
  const config = {action: "read", expires: "03-01-2500"}

  const [[original], ...thumbnails] = await Promise.all([
    bucket.file(filePath).getSignedUrl(config),
    ...thumbFiles
      .map(thumbFile =>
        bucket.file(thumbFile).getSignedUrl(config)
      )
  ])
  // And add the URLs to the database.

  const pictures = {fileName, SIZE_ORIGINAL: original}

  thumbnails.forEach(([thumbnail], index) => {
    pictures[`SIZE_${sizes[index]}`] = thumbnail
  })

  await database.ref(destination).push(pictures)
  return console.log(`urls are pushed to the database at ${destination}.`)
}



/**
 * Delete a picture and its corresponding thumbnails
 * @param {DataSnapshot} snap contains the deleted files' names
 * @param {string} context.params.galleryId the location where the pictures were deleted from
 * @param {string} [context.params.roomId] the id of the room where the pictures were deleted from
 */
export const deletePictures = async (snap, {params: {galleryId, roomId}}) => {
  
  const {fileName} = snap.val()
  let baseURL
  
  if (galleryId) {
    baseURL = `galleries/${galleryId}`
  } else {
    if (roomId) {
      baseURL = `galleries/szobak/${roomId}`
    } else {
      return console.log("Exiting...")
    }
  }

  console.log("Image deletion detected in the database, deleting images from the Storage...")
  

  const files = [`${baseURL}/${fileName}`]
  sizes.forEach(size => {files.push(`${baseURL}/thumb_${size}_${fileName}`)})

  files.forEach(async file => {await storage.bucket().file(file).delete()})

  return console.log(`All versions of ${fileName} are now deleted.`)
}
```

I can't completely understand the reason for the Quota being exceeded, I only generate a few thumbnails, even though those thumbnails will trigger the function as well (then I exit the processing immediately), it should be at most 4 calls since I generate 3 thumbnails.

Comment: Please copy the fully error message into your question.  Right now you're just showing a screenshot of an incomplete message  Use the expander arrow on the message to see the full message and copy it into your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function killed. Error: quota exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905204/function-killed-error-quota-exceeded)

Comment: The error message says exactly what the problem is: you're exceeding the quota for function invocations allowed per 100 seconds. Per the linked question, you are allowed 50 on the free plan.

Comment: If you log `fileName` for each invocation you should be able to quickly see where all the invocations are coming from.